# Write to browser cache

Tags: apache-flex, caching

I have a flex application that downloads a set of information each time the user logs into the site. I was wondering if there was a way to cache that information as it hardly changes. If anyone knows a way of doing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

If the amount of information stored is not big, you can use [Local Shared Objects](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Shared+Objects) to store the information. LSOs are similar to cookies.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I already make use of Shared Objects. The only problem I have is that it's 3Mb of data that is downloads every time. Can Share Objects take that much?

Comment: It depends on user setting, but default it's much lower than that.